# How do I change Wi-Fi Hotspot settings in Ubuntu with GNOME 3?

Tags: networking, wireless, gnome, network-manager, hot-spot

How do I manage my hotspot connected devices or change the hotspot password? I can only see the Network Name, Security type and the Password but I can't seem to manage users or the network properties.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

For some strange reason the default GUI network manager doesn't provide many options. But fortunately there's another tool which does. Open Terminal and run

```
nm-connection-editor
```

A GUI network connection manager should appear which will provide more options to manage your hotspot.

[image]

*Source:* This [Ask Fedora post](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/72669/network-manager-impossible-to-change-settings-of-created-hotspot-wi-fi/)

---

You may also try [this CLI method](https://askubuntu.com/a/971942/) to change your hotspot password as suggested by [Akshar Patel](https://askubuntu.com/users/534414/akshar-patel).

Comment: worked on 18.04 too

Answer (score 3):

I wasn't able to get the graphical tools to respect the ssid change, I was able to find a way to setup a wifi access point directly like so:

```
nmcli dev wifi hotspot ifname wlp4s0 ssid test password "test1234"
```

credit: 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/384513/61349

Comment: thanks, i also changed name in gui with $ nm-connection-editor  but the ssid used was till the name in cat /etc/hostname.
This seem to be a ubuntu wifi bug.