# WiFi hotspot in 17.10

Tags: 17.10, ap-hotspot

I searched a lot but wasn't able to find. Also, there's no option I am able to find in GUI.

How can I change the password for WiFi hotspot in Ubuntu 17.10? It's very urgent.

Thanks for the help and regards!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ nmcli connection modify Hotspot 802-11-wireless-security.key-mgmt wpa-psk 802-11-wireless-security.psk mypassword
```

Just replace `mypassword` with your desired password. Make sure that the password has **at least 8 characters**.

Comment: for gui $ nm-connection-editor