# How to create wifi hotspot in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: networking, wireless, 17.10, hot-spot

I have not found any answer on how to create Wi-Fi hotspot in Ubuntu 17.10.

I have found [how to change the password of an existing hotspot](https://askubuntu.com/a/971942/737915). Also I found [how to create in Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/a/942722/737915), but I can't make it work on Ubuntu 17.10.

Is there any way to achieve that using the default installation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Make sure your Wi-Fi is enabled (not disabled by hardware or toggle in the system menu at the top right).
2. Click on *Activities*, search for *Settings* and open it.
3. Go to **Wi-Fi** section.
4. Click on the vertical ellipsis (three vertical dots) or something similar at the top right to open a pop-up dialogue. You should find a "*Turn On Wi-Fi Hotspot*" option there:
   [image]

Comment: My Android device doesn't see such wi-fi hotspot. Is there a way to solve it?

Comment: @stepaniuk See if this helps: https://askubuntu.com/questions/973784/wi-fi-hotspot-doesnt-transmit-data

Comment: Thanks, but after some digging, it seams that the reason is that my Wi-Fi adapter is just not capable under Linux of Access Point / "Master" mode necessary for Android. This must be caused by the Linux wireless card driver, because I did share internet under Windows 7 with Connectify. https://askubuntu.com/questions/180733/how-to-setup-an-access-point-mode-wi-fi-hotspot/, https://askubuntu.com/questions/490950/create-wifi-hotspot-on-ubuntu/, https://github.com/oblique/create_ap/issues/264