# Wifi hotspot Ubuntu 17.10 activated but there is no wifi list on android phones

Tags: wireless, 17.10, hot-spot

I am using my ethernet cable and wanted to share a connection via wifi hotspot on Ubuntu 17.10. I've been trying to enter the Wifi ID and password manually on my phone in case it is hidden but there is nothing happened. Tested on two android phones.

Comment: no, I got ethernet connection on my laptop and want to share this connection through wifi hotspot @pomsky

Comment: Hmm... no idea what's wrong then. To change hotspot settings and password you may see this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/897854/how-do-i-change-wi-fi-hotspot-settings-in-ubuntu-gnome-16-04

Comment: yeah, checking on your link and try to change connection type form Ad Hoc to Hotspot doesn't work either @pomsky

Comment: See this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/973784/wi-fi-hotspot-doesnt-transmit-data