# Ubuntu 18.04 Hotspot doesn't work

Tags: hot-spot

Recently I needed to use Hotspot, unlike previous versions the process here is very automatic which is very unpleasant in some sense because you can't set your own password or edit other Wi-Fi settings. The first day the Hotspot worked relatively fine while the next day I just couldn't enable it, basically nothing really changed, the internet was working fine but whenever I pressed the button "Turn On Wifi Hotspot" nothing happened. I tried to turn it on with enabled Airplane mode and without it but nothing changed either, I restarted the computer too. I even went further into trying to downgrade to earlier Ubuntu versions but gave up because of painful effort needed to do so. Can someone explain what's the problem?

Comment: See [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/897854/how-do-i-change-wi-fi-hotspot-settings-in-ubuntu-gnome-16-04) for the editing hotspot part.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this answer here: [Create wireless access point and share internet connection with nmcli](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/384513)

That is to say:

```
  nmcli dev wifi hotspot ifname wlp4s0 ssid <name> password "<password>"
```

Where the fields name and password are custom.

If `wlp4s0` does not work for your case, doing a double <kbd>Tab</kbd> can fill the field automatically.

Comment: Worked on `wlp2s0`... while my network-manager of linux mint did fail - maybe network-manager did auto-generate too long / wrong SSID using computer-name.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is the problem actually! but i had the same problem, hotspot works fine only at the fist time.
so i just did `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` and changed hotspot ssid with `nm-connection-editor` command then with turned on wifi and turned off airplane mode, i opened hotspot again and my hotspot is working properly now.

Answer (score 0):

For me,

`$ sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager`

worked.